# Math Symbols in Index (makeindex)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, indexing, makeindex

I want to have the following Symbol in my Index (with makeindex):

```
$\| \cdot \|_X$
```

I tried alot, however nothing worked, it wont show.
I tried:

```
Test\index{Norm!1@$|| \cdot ||$}
Test2\index{Norm!1@$1_X$}
Test3\index{Norm!1@$\| \cdot \|_X$}
```

None of these Commands work, when I try

```
Test3\index{Norm!1@$Test$}
```

it works. What do I wrong? Can anybody show me a code where I can display these Symbols?
Thank you.

Comment: just use `\Vert` instead of `\|`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character `|` is special for MakeIndex, so you need to escape it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

Test\index{Norm!1@$"|"| \cdot "|"|$}
Test2\index{Norm!1@$1_X$}
Test3\index{Norm!1@$"\"| \cdot "\"|_X$}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The `.ind` file will contain

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item Norm
    \subitem $1_X$, 1
    \subitem $\| \cdot \|_X$, 1
    \subitem $|| \cdot ||$, 1

\end{theindex}
```

Don't use `||` for the norm, though.

A better way to input norms is with `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newcommand{\blank}{{\;\cdot\;}}

\begin{document}

Test\index{Norm!1@$\norm{\blank}$}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

(I added some dummy entries for avoiding a two-line index.)

Comment: Not related with the question, but in `mathtools` documentation is suggested (not sure if suggested is the right word) to use `\DclarePairedDelimiterX…` in combination with `\ifblank…` from `etoolbox` instead of your `\blank` command. Is there a reason to prefer one over the other? Or, it was done like this to avoid the use of a package not directly related to the question?

Comment: @LuisTurcio I see no relation between my`\blank` (to denote the signpost for a variable) and `\ifblank` of `etoolbox`.

Comment: Sorry if I have been unclear. In `mathtools` manual there is an example of the norm, page 29. It goes something like this `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\norm}[1]{\lVert}{\rVert}{\ifblank{#1}{\;\cdot\;}{#1}}` (it uses `etoolbox`). Then, your `\norm{\blank}` will be equivalent to `\norm{}`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the first MWE by *egreg* but found some shortcomings. I could not combine `hyperref` and `imakefile`.

Consider this index command

```
  \index{$"\"| \cdot"\"|_Y$! the norm on space \(Y\)}
```

If `hyperref`  is loaded before  `imakeidx` then the index does not use smart links.

If `imakeidx` is loaded before `hyperref` then the `.idx` file contains

```
\indexentry{$"\"|hyperindexformat{\ \cdot"\"}}{4}
```

and this fails

To solve the problem I used the `‖` unicode character (that is `U+2016 DOUBLE VERTICAL LINE` ) in the index command

```
\index{$‖ \cdot ‖_Y$! the norm on space \(Y\)}
```

so the `.idx` file contains

```
\indexentry{$‖\cdot‖_X$! the norm on space \(X\)|hyperpage}{4}
```

This (of course) requires the use of `xelatex` or `lualatex`, as in this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\index{$‖ \cdot ‖_Y$! the norm on space \(Y\)}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

If you do not like unicode, you can use `\Vert` instead of `‖`

PS: the second MWE by `egreg` works fine with `hyperref`, but I would rather not rewrap all norms inside a `\norm` command.. IMHO `$‖ \cdot ‖_Y$` is more readable.